# CAS apereo 5.3: Create customized MFA

Tags: java, xml, cas, multi-factor-authentication

I have been trying to create my own customized MFA for cas apereo 5.3 using the official doc unsuccessfully, and i didn't find any other docs that can help me out understand the concept.
I wonder if anyone have tutorials or hints that can help me solve my problem.

Official doc : https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Custom-MFA-Authentication.html

Custom MFA example: https://github.com/EsupPortail/esup-otp-cas/tree/5.2.x/src/main

Thank you.